# Obtener nombre de la imagen asignada

Tags: objective-c

Como puedo obtener el nombre de la imagen que tiene asignada una `UIImageview` o `UIButton` o `UILabel`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto no se puede realizar, la razón es simplemente que la instancia de `UIImageview`, `UIButton` o `UILabel` no almacena la imagen!. Además de que solo despliega una instancia de la imagen (UIImage).

No se almacena una referencia o el path de la imagen.
https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiimageview